# Having issue in implement api calling using alamofire

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, uikit

I am using alamofire using for loop web 3 call but the issue is I changed the chain then crashed the app in web3 call. Cam you solve this issue or anyone help me to new api call then previous all async call stopped then new request? The issue in this line `group.addTask { return await web3wrapper.shared }` How do I solve this concurrent call?

```swift
func processHistoryDetails(historyDetail: History) async -> [String: Any]? {
    let logHistoryCount = historyDetail.logHistory?.count ?? 0
    var processWeb3Call: [String: Any]?
    await withTaskGroup(of: [String: Any]?.self) {[weak self] group in
        guard let self = self else {return}
        for i in 0 ..< logHistoryCount {
            let firstIndexDecodedEventParams = historyDetail.logHistory?[i].decodedEvent?.params?.firstIndex(where: { event in
                event.name == "value"
            }) ?? -1
            if firstIndexDecodedEventParams != -1 {
                let contractAddress = historyDetail.logHistory?[i].address
                let value = historyDetail.logHistory?[i].decodedEvent?.params?[firstIndexDecodedEventParams].value ?? "0"
                group.cancelAll()
                group.addTask {
                    return await Web3Wrapper.shared.processValue(contractAddress: contractAddress!, value: value, chainId: self.activeChain.chainId, rpcUrl: self.activeChain.rpcUrl)
                }
            }
        }
        for await result in group {
            if let result = result {
                processWeb3Call = result
            }
        }
    }
    return processWeb3Call
}
```

[image]

Comment: What error do you get when it crash and do you know which line it is that causes the crash?

Comment: Why is there a `group.cancelAll()`? If there is a crash, is there an error message in console? You changed? What was the previous (supposedly working) code?

Comment: i attached the image can you once click on image and guide me how to solve this issue ? i tried group.cancell all but the issue is memory leaks @Larme

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of possible improvements here (simplify `if let foo = foo {…}` to `if let foo {…}`; get rid of the `-1` logic; the `[weak self]` capture pattern is not doing what you think it is; etc.), but let’s focus on the “start a bunch of asynchronous requests, but cancel all prior ones and only save the result of the last one”.

The idea of adding a task after canceling the group will not work because, as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskgroup/cancelall()/) says, “If you add a task to a group after canceling the group, that task is canceled immediately after being added to the group.”

So, if the intent is really not turn run these multiple requests concurrently, but rather to cancel all but the last request, I would suggest instead:

1. Given there is only one task that will actually run, identify that one, and only start it, not even starting all the others at all; and, therefore
2. Retire the task group pattern entirely, as that only makes sense if you really want to run multiple tasks concurrently.

E.g., you could loop through your log history in reverse order, identify the one that passes whatever criteria you want, and return just that one, and not both starting a bunch of tasks that you want to just cancel:

```swift
func processHistoryDetails(historyDetail: History) async -> [String: Any]? {
    guard let logHistory = historyDetail.logHistory else { return nil }
    
    for log in logHistory.reversed() {
        if
            let param = log.decodedEvent?.params?.first(where: { $0.name == "value" }),
            let address = log.address
        {
            return await Web3Wrapper.shared.processValue(
                contractAddress: address, 
                value: param.value ?? "0", 
                chainId: activeChain.chainId, 
                rpcUrl: activeChain.rpcUrl
            )
        }            
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

All of that having been said, there is a good chance that this “adding task to a canceled group” is not the source of the crash. A more likely candidate is the forced-unwrapping operator, `!`. If that optional was `nil`, that will crash the app. It is always better to `guard let` or `if let`. So, rather than force-unwrapping the address, I added it to the `if let` clause. (Also, I do not know if those other variables are implicitly unwrapped optionals, but if so, that is another potential source of problems.)

Anyway, there are lots of permutations on the theme, but the idea is to simply not start tasks that you are going to cancel, anyway, and avoid forced unwrapping of optionals.